# Debugger isn't honoring changes to my WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I've got a C#/WPF application which was originally built in Visual Studio 2012. Eventually we upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and that worked fine. Lately I've upgraded further to Visual Studio 2017 and now I'm having lots of problems. I've got the drop-down options set to "Debug," "Mixed Platforms," and my project name, and when I hit Start it does indeed start up my project. However any recent changes I make to the project don't get reflected.

At first I was wondering why a TouchUp event handler I had added wasn't seeming to be hit. Then after further experimentation, I changed one of the existing log messages slightly (we have a logger that logs to a local text file). However, it continues to log the old message. Another symptom of this is that none of my breakpoints get hit. When I add them it shows up as the standard red circle, but as soon as I press start they change to a white circle with a red perimeter, and the tool-tip hint says that it cannot hit the breakpoint because the source does not match what is running.

This is extremely frustrating as the debugger is one of those things that should just work. Has anyone else run into anything similar after upgrading to VS'17? Any advice?

Comment: Did you build the project before starting debugging (note there's a setting to do that automatically)? Are you sure the exe being debugged is the one built?

Comment: I did try building the project before debugging, yes. For your second question, how would I check that?

Comment: Check in the Modules window which exe is loaded, and which pdbs. Note that if you did build, but still see old source in effect (eg the message being logged you talk about), it really seems you are not debugging the correct exe.

Comment: Hmmm, it's using the files in MyProject\bin\Debug\* but they seem to be two months old. Also strange is that the Release files also seem to be old, despite me having hit "Build" just this morning. I'm going to try deleting all those files, but you mentioned there is an option to force a rebuild before debugging... do you happen to know where I can find that option?

Comment: Tools->Options->Build and Run. It doesn't *re*build before debugging, just builds. Also check the build output, it shows the path to the exe it creates. Then check why it does that (i.e. output path in the project config). Also check in the project settings what exe is getting debugged.

Comment: You might have added your references incorrectly

Comment: having the same issue... the workaround @SoaperGEM has mentioned does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround to my problem, but not a solution. When I deleted the files from the "bin" folder, it just stopped working altogether. So instead I manually built the project using MSBuild, in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin folder. The two commands I ran in succession were:

```
MSBuild.exe /target:Clean /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU" MySolution.sln

MSBuild.exe /target:Build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU" MySolution.sln
```

In fact, I don't really need to do the "Clean" step every time, and this works. However it's really quite slow and I am genuinely surprised that VS apparently isn't doing this automatically, under the hood.

Comment: It is,. If your project stopped working, it's because you had references to dlls or other files in the build folder itself. Or, you may have a pre-build event that expects to find stuff in there already.

Comment: Is the "build folder" different from the bin folders?

Comment: Visual Studio only builds projects that have changed. If you click on *Rebuild*, it cleans the build folders of all projects in the solution before building

Comment: I can tell you based on the results I'm getting that it is not doing that. I don't deny that it *should* be doing that.

Comment: Consider this. Don't you think that thousands of developers wouldn't have noticed in the last 15 years? Or even in the last year, for 2017? Create a *new*, clean project and check the build behaviour there

Comment: @SoaperGEM, After you rebuild it using MSbuild, how about the result if you re-edit your code and debug it in VS IDE? Maybe run VS as the admin, or your solution include different projects and this one was added as the reference, if so, please check the Build configuration manager window, and make sure that all projects enable the "Build" option. Anyway, since you find a workaround and resolve this issue, you could also mark it as the answer before we found a better solution.